# How can I search in responses

Tags: support, comments

I remember, I was suggested some books (links to books) in comments to my questions or answers, but now I can't find them easily.

How can I search for such links (for example by 'book' keyword)?

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way. For a not-that-hard way, see the api: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/user-inbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first option, while not optimal, is trivial to do.  Go to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/151256/ahmad?tab=responses and page through them one at a time and read them. It works and doesn't require any additional hoops. I've even done this for myself at times to find things, and I have 89 pages of responses.

You can also poke at http://data.stackexchange.com/ and write some SQL.  http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/revision/376067/484421/ will pull back all comments on posts by a given user id - for you this is likely enough as there are only 121 rows. While the current version http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/revision/376067/484422 has a keyword in there too which can be used to filter.  Your user id is `151256` (you can see it in the URL for your profile `https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/151256/ahmad` )

For what its worth, there is only one comment that exists on any of your posts that has the word 'book' in it -

> "Why algorithms textbook are more procedure-oriented?" Java is also procedure-oriented. Java is an object oriented procedural language. – Pieter B Feb 6 at 8:01

([Relation between object orientation and algorithms](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/272298/relation-between-object-orientation-and-algorithms#comment556547_272298))

Extending the query to find comments on answers to questions that a given user posted is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thank you very much for the work! that is a useful query! I found a link to a paper by searching "read", however for the book, I may have got it in another site of stackexchange!

Comment: @Ahmad you can see the site name in the link to the data.SE site. On the data.SE site you can also type in the 'switch sites' field (near the bottom) that will allow you to do the search on other sites.